# Proving $\frac\pi{22}\cos\frac\pi{22}+\frac{2\pi}{11}\cos\frac{5\pi }{22}+\frac{2\pi}{ 11}\cos\frac{9\pi}{22}+\frac\pi{22}\cos\frac{5\pi}{11}<\cdots$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

$$(\frac{\pi}{22}) \cos (\frac{\pi}{22}) +(\frac{2\pi}{11}) \cos (\frac{5\pi }{22}) + (\frac{2\pi}{ 11}) \cos (\frac{9\pi}{22}) + (\frac{\pi}{22})  \cos(\frac{5\pi}{11}) < (\frac{\pi}{26}) +(\frac{3\pi}{13}) \cos(\frac{\pi}{26})+ (\frac{3\pi}{13})\cos(\frac{7\pi}{26})$$

It will be a basic problem in Calculus, but as of now I have no clue to solve. Please give some hints.

Comment: Have you tried expanding as a power series to see what happens? Just a thought.

Comment: Dividing by $\pi$ is an obvious first step.