# Proving a trigonometric inequality which is related to calculus

Tags: calculus

I need to prove the following inequality, without the help of a calculator. This problem was given to me in an exam. It is a trigonometric inequality but is somehow related to calculus (as that was the topic of the exam). Even if you could tell me to which topic of calculus is this question related, it would be very helpful. All help is greatly appreciated!

$$\left(\frac{\pi}{22}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{22}\right)+\left(\frac{2\pi}{11}\right)\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{22}\right)+\left(\frac{2\pi}{11}\right)\cos\left(\frac{9\pi}{22}\right)+\left(\frac{\pi}{22}\right)\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{11}\right)<\left(\frac{\pi}{26}\right)+\left(\frac{3\pi}{13}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{26}\right)+\left(\frac{3\pi}{13}\right)\cos\left(\frac{7\pi}{26}\right)$$

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905870/proving-frac-pi22-cos-frac-pi22-frac2-pi11-cos-frac5-pi-22-frac

Comment: Thanks for the link. In the exam I did try and use power series, but the equation got complicated quickly, and my teacher assures me that there is a neater way of solving the problem.